# Is there a way to get the response to a message sent with programmable messaging without using webhooks

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

For security reasons my application of the twilio programmable messaging API can't receive webhooks. Is there a way to make a some other API call (like a GET) to see if there is a response to the message we sent?

Answer (score 0):

Reference this blog, that is one approach. Using Amazon SQS.

[Handling High Volume Inbound SMS and Webhooks with Twilio Functions and Amazon SQS](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/07/handling-high-volume-inbound-sms-and-webhooks-with-twilio-functions-and-amazon-sqs.html)

> This can also be handy if you don’t have a public webhook URL you can
> configure with Twilio, and would rather process these messages by
> polling SQS from the comfort of your own internal servers.

You could also post the inbound SMS to an Airtable base, and pull it from that SB table. Lots of options.